# Can't write <word>.<word> while using eclim

Tags: vim, eclim

When i try to write `import org.junit.Test`, just when I have completed writing `import.jun` it converts(auto-completes) it to `import org.jun=acp#onPopupPost()`.

Is it some eclim autocomplete feature which is misbehaving or something else? I only face this issue when I am inside a project opened via eclim. Other wise there is no issue.

Comment: Obviously. You are using AutoComplPop and it breaks there. You should create an issue on the plugin's github page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a problem with the [AutoComplPop plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879); part of its mapping is inserted literally. I'm using the plugin myself, but haven't seen that issue. It may be interference with another plugin; have you done any updates to other plugins recently?! If you can reproduce the problem with a clean .vimrc and no other plugins loaded, submit an issue to the author.

To temporarily disable the plugin (without uninstalling), put the following into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:loaded_acp = 1
```

Comment: No I haven't. Is there a way to disable the plugin temporarily?

Comment: I have version 2.14.1-1 installed, Have you tried it with Eclim running? because I can not reproduce the problem if I'm not inside a project opened via eclim.

Comment: I have `2.14.1`; you can temporarily disable it; see my edit.

Comment: Seems like a bug in AutoComplPop. Filed an issue.